# Tag is empty when using brush in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, brush

This question is related to [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17325205/how-to-brush-the-plot-and-then-save-the-brushed-data-in-gui).

I have followed the example from there:

```
t=0:0.2:25; plot(t,sin(t),'.-');
brush on
pause
hBrushLine = findall(gca,'tag','Brushing');
brushedData = get(hBrushLine, {'Xdata','Ydata'});
brushedIdx = ~isnan(brushedData{1});
brushedXData = brushedData{1}(brushedIdx);
brushedYData = brushedData{2}(brushedIdx);
```

However, `findall(gca,'tag','Brushing')` is empty. 
In fact, looking at the properties of `gca`, the label `Tag` is empty after setting `brush on`.

I have MATLAB 2016a and we have also tested MATLAB 2015a.

Does anyone know how to find the selected data?

Regards
Erik

Answer (score 1):

So the answer is [here](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/hidden-hg2-plot-functionality):

```
hLine = get(gca,'Children');
hBrushHandles = hLine.BrushHandles;
hBrushChildrenHandles = hBrushHandles.Children;  % Marker, LineStrip
hBrushChildrenHandles(1).VertextData
```

This is as I understand it from Matlab 2014 and onwards.

Regards
Erik